# WithStyles injected props type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am wrapping my class component with material UI withStyles to inject classes as a property.

```
export default withStyles(styles)(myComponent)
```

I have

```
const styles = ( (theme:Theme) => createStyles({className:CSS_PROPERTIES})
```

I am trying to declare an interface for my props as follows

```
interface MyComponentProps { classes : any }
```

What should I put instead of ANY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this documentation piece](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#augmenting-your-props-using-withstyles), here is how you should do it:

```
import { withStyles, createStyles, Theme, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = (theme:Theme) => createStyles({className:CSS_PROPERTIES})

interface MyComponentProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
    // you can type additional none-style related props of MyComponent here..
}

const MyComponent = ({ classes }: MyComponentProps) => {

     // your component logic ....

};

export default withStyles(styles)(myComponent)
```